# Aggregate functions to specific values in a Group By query

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have this data (for example):

```
 id         col1        col2
--------------------------------
 5614       (null)      Y
 5614       Y           (null)  
 5614       Y           (null)
```

I want to obtain a single line where it tells me if the fields has some value `Y`.

```
 id         col1        col2
 5614       Y           Y
```

If no value `Y` present, then it should be `N`.

My actual query do that, but I think it should be a shorter way:

```
SELECT op.id, 
CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END AS col1,
CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END AS col2  
FROM OPERATOR op LEFT JOIN TRAM_OP tr ON op.id = tr.id AND tr.id2 = 20
WHERE op.id = 5614 GROUP BY op.id
```

As you can see I have two tables and I need to join them to match the `id2` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a shorthand that eliminates the need for some of the `case` statements:

```
SELECT op.id, 
       (CASE WHEN SUM(col1 = 'S') > 0 THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END) AS col1,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(col2 = 'S') > 0 THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END) AS col2  
FROM OPERATOR op LEFT JOIN
     TRAM_OP tr
     ON op.id = tr.id AND tr.id2 = 20
WHERE op.id = 5614
GROUP BY op.id;
```

You could also take advantage of the fact the `'S'` > `'N'`:

```
SELECT op.id, MAX(col1) AS col1, MAX(col2) AS col2  
FROM OPERATOR op LEFT JOIN
     TRAM_OP tr
     ON op.id = tr.id AND tr.id2 = 20
WHERE op.id = 5614
GROUP BY op.id;
```

However, this version might be confusing to someone else reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

If `Y` is the only possible value, then with a simple `max`, you get either this value or NULL:

```
SELECT id, max(col1) AS col1, max(col2) AS col2
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY id
```

You can change the NULL to `'N'` with the [ifnull function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
SELECT id,
       ifnull(max(col1), 'N') AS col1,
       ifnull(max(col2), 'N') AS col2
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID,
case when Col1 > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'COL1', 
case when Col2 > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'COL2' 
from
(
    Select id,SUM(case when Col1 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end)'COL1', SUM(
        case when Col2 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end
    )'COL2'
    from #temp
    group by id
) t
```